# The best way to overwrite FBC to CBV with redirection to correct slug

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a FB view that shows all products of current brand:

```
def brand_products(request, brand_id, slug):
    brand = get_object_or_404(Brand, id=brand_id)
    if slug != brand.name_for_url:
        return redirect(brand)
    products = brand.product_set.all()
    return render(request, 'products.html',
              {'products': products})
```

I want to rewrite it to CBV, here is what I get:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Brand
    context_object_name = 'products'
    template_name = 'products.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.brand = get_object_or_404(Brand, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if self.kwargs['brand_slug'] != self.brand.name_for_url:
            return redirect(self.brand)
        else:
            products = self.brand.product_set.all()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'products':products})
```

I can't set queryset in `get_queryset` method, but then I can't redirect page to the same page with correct url. I get object by primarykey, but if `slug` is not correct, then I will redirect page to correct url with correct slug(`name_for_url`).  in this case, `FBV` is shorter then `CBV`. Maybe are there other solutions in `CBV`?

Comment: the only point to class-based views is if they make your life easier

Comment: What is the problem with `get_queryset` method?

Comment: @Gocht I can't redirect in `get_queryset` method

Comment: @user3525271 `get_queryset` method will return a `QuerySet` object. Why do you need redirect there? See this -> http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.list/ListView/

Comment: @Gocht, I understand you. I get my products by foreignkey to `brand`. This fk I get from url, but for human-readable url I add slug to it. If user entered correct id but incorrect slug(in my case `name_for_url`), I need to redirect page to the same url but with correct slug that is in database for proper id. My explaination seems to be complicated, but `stackoverflow` acts the same. try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726267/example_here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726267/example_here) , and it will redirect you to my question but with correct slug, not with `example_here`

Comment: @user3525271 But why in `get_queryset` method? I think you can do that in `get` method, redirecting with the obtained slug.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the function based view works, you don't necessarily gain anything by converting to a class based view.

If you really want a CBV, then I would do less in the `get` method. Fetch the `brand`, redirect if necessary, but otherwise call `super()`

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.brand = get_object_or_404(Brand, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    if self.kwargs['brand_slug'] != self.brand.name_for_url:
        return redirect(self.brand)
    else:
        return super(ProductListView, self).get(request, *args,  **kwargs)
```

Then you can access `self.brand` in the `get_queryset` method.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.brand.product_set.all()
```